# How to integrate JasperServer into Liferay

Tags: jasper-reports, liferay, jasperserver

How can I integrate JasperServer 4 to Liferay 6? I found [an article](http://www.ochounos.com/?blog&entry=8) that describes how to integrate JasperServer CE 3.7.0 into Liferay 6.0.5. But I doubt that it won't be applicable to version 4. I check http://sourceforge.net and found [a portlet for JasperServer 3.7.1](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jasperserver/files/JasperServer/JasperServer%203.7.1/). However, there is no JasperServerPortlet for version 4 in the web site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's one here:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/jasperserver/files/JasperServer/JasperReports%20Server%204.7.0/ - JasperReportsServer-portlet-4.7.0.war

Note though that it's intended for JBoss portal, so it's possible something won't work in Liferay. Unfortunately, this would mean you'd have to develop your own integration for Liferay.